# How can I check the url before calling history.back()?

Tags: javascript, angular, url, navigation, browser-history

Basically I want to check if `history.back()` which I call on button click takes me to an external page and block the button in this case

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you cannot get the previous external web url. Check out this history API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History

However, if the external page is not important by its value, but only for being external one, you could trick it. Just preserve a route state when navigation across **your** application.

When a user navigates from your app to other page in the app, set a state indicating that the previous page was internal one. Then, once a user clicks your button, check that state and act according to its value.

**Example:**

Pass data on navigation:

```
this.router.navigate(['/some-internal-page', { internal: true }]);
```

Read data:

```
this.isInternal = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('internal'));
```

Then, when a user clicks the button, act in accordance to `this.isInternal` value.